# Charts in C# ASPNET

Tags: c#, graph, charts

I 'm trying to use the CHARTS and I can do what I want.
But, at this point, I need to do better graphs.
How can I change the x and y axis values?
I'm using a objectdatasource to populate the graph.

Tks in advance.

Comment: Add some code, maybe an image of what you want to do.

Comment: If you want to add something to your question, edit what your already posted, do not add an answer. Also you could post a link to the image, i.e. from imgur.

Answer (score 0):

*Change the x and y values* is still a bit obscure, you could try to set manually the X and Y value type

```
Chart1.Series["s1"].XValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;
```

If you don't display properly the `DataPoints`.